# Posting a "progressive" answer to one's own question

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/q/615399/26316). It doesn't seem likely to get a suitable answer any time soon, and as such I've decided to work on the problem myself. I want to describe my solution in an answer while I'm working on it (writing the code). This will result in a large number of edits to the answer while I develop the solution. Is this considered bad form? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it's preferable to have one final answer, there's nothing wrong in having a progressive answer - the number of edits, however, will bump up the post to the front page - you might have to deal with the voting consequences (few people might consider downvoting your post because it's incomplete).

The other problem is beyond 11 edits, the post will become an auto Community Wiki - this, however, shouldn't be a problem - you can flag for CW reversal.

On the top of my head, [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek) had a similar [progressive question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/342107/getting-macro-keys-from-a-razer-blackwidow-to-work-on-linux) running from [Oct'11 to Feb'12](https://superuser.com/posts/342107/revisions).